# Using Java15 and IntelliJ, Unable to resolve mockito symbol

Tags: java, intellij-idea, mockito

Trying to learn TDD with mock but intelliJ says unable to resolve mockito symbol.

This is my code

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;



public class AccountTest {

    @Test public void
    store_a_deposit_transaction(){
        verify(transactionRepository).addDeposit(100);
        Mockito.
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Are you trying to showcase that you're not getting any suggestions by your IDE when typing `Mockito.` ?

Comment: I am not getting any suggestions from intelliJ when typing Mockito, basically I am unable to use Mockito.

Comment: Have you tried invoking any of the library-methods without typing `Mockito` (which is the point of statically importing it). Do you get any suggestions if you try e.g. `when()`?